# JUnit 5 @Tag does not work as expected with @BeforeEach/@AfterEach

Tags: java, maven, junit

Have a simple math operations test suite developed with JUnit 5.
I use two tags `@Tag("add")` and `@Tag("minus")`.

With maven and surefire plugin I select the tag for the tests.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
  <configuration combine.children="append">
    <excludedGroups></excludedGroups>
    <groups>add</groups>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

When I do the `mvn test` on the terminal it will execute only the tests marked by the `@Tag("add")` but for some reason will execute the `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` tagged exclusively with `@Tag("minus")`

```
@Tag("minus")
@BeforeEach
void beforeEach(TestInfo test) { /* code */ }

@Tag("minus")
@AfterEach
void afterEach(TestInfo test) { /* code */ }
```

Since the expected behaviour was not working, I even forced with `<excludedGroups>`, changed from empty value to `<excludedGroups>minus</excludedGroups>` on `pom.xml`, still not worked.

There is something wrong on `pom.xml` that I'm missing?

A conflict between `@Tag` and `@BeforeEach` plus `@AfterEach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the @Tag annotation was conceived just to clasify your tests following a common characteristic. If you need different setUp() and teardown() I guess the righ way to go is to separate them in different test classes, not with the tag annotation.

In the documentation it is describes it can be used in a test class or a test method:

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Tag.html

Answer (score 4):

[@Tag](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering) is meant for test classes and methods. It has nothing to do with setup/teardown of said tests.

You could either split those tests into separate test classes or you could leverage [Nested Test](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested). Nested tests could look something like this:

```
@DisplayName("A stack")
class MathTest {

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("when new")
    @Tag("add")
    class Add {

        @BeforeEach
        void setupAdding() {
            // ...
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("can add")
        void canAdd() {
            // ...
        }

    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("minus")
    @Tag("minus")
    class Minus {

        @BeforeEach
        void setupMinus() {
            // ...
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("can subtract")
        void testMinus() {
            // ...
        }

    }
}
```